# Android App Widget: Data storage

Tags: android, widget, storage

I'm implementing a home screen app widget. I was wondering which is better to store/read data: SharedPreferences or a SQLite database? The data is accessed from an AppWidgetProvider (similar to a BroadcastReceiver), and any given instance of the widget displays different data based on appWidgetId. Is one way or the other frowned upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your use case. Preferences are meant to be a simple, lightweight mechanism to store key-value type of data while an SQLite database provides you with a whole framework for storing and retrieving relational data (queries, transactions, etc.).

[This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) gives an overview of both and also covers custom files and network as alternative ways to persist data.

Comment: Thank you Josef. I was sold at "lightweight mechanism".